# How do I melt/gather multiple variables (error bars) into one for mapping to geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, melt, geom-bar

I'll start with my goal which is to generate graphs for each of my variables (magnitude [mag], duration [dura] and distance [dist] but with **distinct error bars for train and test.** :

Almost finished graph
[image]

I have a data-frame that looks like this: (screenshot + dput below). It shows the responses (magnitude, distance, duration) during train and test of various biological strains along with their standard error (SEM). For example, the duration response at train is in column "train_avg_dura" and at test is "test_avg_dura". The standard error for each of these is in the columns train_duraSEM and test_duraSEM

**df_group_sum.wide (data-frame)**

```
dput data:
df_group_sum.wide <-
structure(list(strain = structure(1:8, .Label = c("N2", "acy-1(LOF)",
"acy-1(GOF)", "pde-4", "unc-43", "crh-1", "glr-1", "avr-14"), class = "factor"),
test_avg_dist = c(0.23102447163515, 0.198503787878788, 0.23892936802974,
0.247270588235294, 0.148316666666667, 0.195762711864407,
0.204740740740741, 0.238755154639175), test_avg_dura = c(1.04759733036707,
1.15537878787879, 0.914684014869888, 1.12286274509804, 0.828916666666667,
0.785491525423729, 0.788407407407407, 1.02309278350515),
test_avg_mag = c(0.112163461525871, 0.113447031611172, 0.15930172539742,
0.105397926645665, 0.0370000063024116, 0.0823626968797451,
0.0441620688813484, 0.135786546158742), test_distSEM = c(0.00460504533342531,
0.0050568065734325, 0.00945562739572128, 0.00524044558789062,
0.00882224860763199, 0.00983820301449839, 0.0162322856355826,
0.00738407922404085), test_duraSEM = c(0.0187491841242793,
0.0287113186085301, 0.0283764910080623, 0.0215386973519077,
0.0471018319675206, 0.0341593217329755, 0.0564553992545153,
0.0271939362203803), test_magSEM = c(0.00335619679815181,
0.00443251320170775, 0.00919066553588191, 0.00432150262248429,
0.00400887448034098, 0.00664866437888279, 0.00575860867691942,
0.00524462205156711), train_avg_dist = c(0.337652222222222,
0.294218518518519, 0.338651851851852, 0.311313725490196,
0.254675, 0.2737, 0.390688888888889, 0.314817948717949),
train_avg_dura = c(1.3543, 1.429, 1.19151851851852, 1.37256862745098,
1.236, 1.06376666666667, 1.41396296296296, 1.31512820512821
), train_avg_mag = c(0.1930557426236, 0.19297076970836, 0.212916856705011,
0.127417008935649, 0.0841239843171108, 0.117210954090848,
0.115413610503398, 0.179227387006556)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("strain",
"test_avg_dist", "test_avg_dura", "test_avg_mag", "test_distSEM",
"test_duraSEM", "test_magSEM", "train_avg_dist", "train_avg_dura",
"train_avg_mag"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

[image: data-frame I start with]

**The problem I am having is how to add error bars using SEM since I need them to be merged into one variable as opposed to two when I map the variable to geom_bar. I think this is a melt issue but I can't figure it out.**

**Update:**

The melted data-frame I used to plot the graph is as follows:

```
structure(list(strain = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("N2", "acy-1(LOF)", 
"acy-1(GOF)", "pde-4", "unc-43", "crh-1", "glr-1", "avr-14"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
    17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("test_avg_dist", 
    "test_avg_dura", "test_avg_mag", "test_avg_prob", "test_avg_spd", 
    "test_distSEM", "test_duraSEM", "test_magSEM", "test_probSEM", 
    "test_spdSEM", "train_avg_dist", "train_avg_dura", "train_avg_mag", 
    "train_avg_prob", "train_avg_spd", "train_distSEM", "train_duraSEM", 
    "train_magSEM", "train_probSEM", "train_spdSEM"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.23102447163515, 0.198503787878788, 0.23892936802974, 
    0.247270588235294, 0.148316666666667, 0.195762711864407, 
    0.204740740740741, 0.238755154639175, 1.04759733036707, 1.15537878787879, 
    0.914684014869888, 1.12286274509804, 0.828916666666667, 0.785491525423729, 
    0.788407407407407, 1.02309278350515, 0.112163461525871, 0.113447031611172, 
    0.15930172539742, 0.105397926645665, 0.0370000063024116, 
    0.0823626968797451, 0.0441620688813484, 0.135786546158742, 
    0.457040018571118, 0.563727434411572, 0.624264612406578, 
    0.392625726149316, 0.219488346025285, 0.355836464305103, 
    0.158243463050796, 0.549997886634136, 0.218104671667048, 
    0.175578055416405, 0.256197987699313, 0.218534931269605, 
    0.181253278716812, 0.235434749265196, 0.236043513165036, 
    0.229165553562148, 0.00460504533342531, 0.0050568065734325, 
    0.00945562739572128, 0.00524044558789062, 0.00882224860763199, 
    0.00983820301449839, 0.0162322856355826, 0.00738407922404085, 
    0.0187491841242793, 0.0287113186085301, 0.0283764910080623, 
    0.0215386973519077, 0.0471018319675206, 0.0341593217329755, 
    0.0564553992545153, 0.0271939362203803, 0.00335619679815181, 
    0.00443251320170775, 0.00919066553588191, 0.00432150262248429, 
    0.00400887448034098, 0.00664866437888279, 0.00575860867691942, 
    0.00524462205156711, 0.00460504533342531, 0.0050568065734325, 
    0.00945562739572128, 0.00524044558789062, 0.00882224860763199, 
    0.00983820301449839, 0.0162322856355826, 0.00738407922404085, 
    0.00148090077905166, 0.00224725406956702, 0.00293788372166611, 
    0.00142518092482957, 0.00475313026432338, 0.00259537819051875, 
    0.00439432015310276, 0.00179190641262238, 0.337652222222222, 
    0.294218518518519, 0.338651851851852, 0.311313725490196, 
    0.254675, 0.2737, 0.390688888888889, 0.314817948717949, 1.3543, 
    1.429, 1.19151851851852, 1.37256862745098, 1.236, 1.06376666666667, 
    1.41396296296296, 1.31512820512821, 0.1930557426236, 0.19297076970836, 
    0.212916856705011, 0.127417008935649, 0.0841239843171108, 
    0.117210954090848, 0.115413610503398, 0.179227387006556, 
    0.525206741295172, 0.606796097537911, 0.592920766963248, 
    0.383218177729097, 0.294853306191478, 0.37983654970313, 0.244065736387288, 
    0.529995494304863, 0.245519078777542, 0.204069564920836, 
    0.279438682643543, 0.223741850875084, 0.203505986396722, 
    0.244494243449087, 0.263225928969608, 0.235094347033923, 
    0.00509151719343593, 0.00741331297357774, 0.0110354960774679, 
    0.0058641318136066, 0.0114389388703232, 0.0108143010933781, 
    0.0182904578688527, 0.00913426247712326, 0.0167858570502119, 
    0.0279705569908445, 0.030133138276768, 0.0219057666071679, 
    0.0479637760140276, 0.0332974908188985, 0.0605392786801207, 
    0.0323033076008837, 0.00498395111761598, 0.0081988397756359, 
    0.0107052683837969, 0.00442352355941589, 0.00723029142814287, 
    0.00764631328347674, 0.00980735575566329, 0.00789476278044047, 
    0.00509151719343593, 0.00741331297357774, 0.0110354960774679, 
    0.0058641318136066, 0.0114389388703232, 0.0108143010933781, 
    0.0182904578688527, 0.00913426247712326, 0.00139403793044242, 
    0.00220415921330836, 0.00299625483623813, 0.00144528089431754, 
    0.00441088530148196, 0.00248394605240026, 0.00319027562414684, 
    0.00174638373495128)), row.names = c(NA, -160L), .Names = c("strain", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

The code I used to plot this (after removing SEM rows) is as follows:

```
    (abs_bar_mag <- 
    df_group_sum.long %>% 
    filter(grepl("mag", variable)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = strain,
               y = value,
               fill = variable))+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightseagreen", "indianred1"))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
    #geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-1, ymax=value+1), width=.1, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 20),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
    ggtitle("") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 30, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 70),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 40),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1,  size = 40),
          axis.title.y = (element_text(size = 65)))
  +
    labs(colour = "",
         y = "Magnitude",
         x = "") +
    scale_colour_manual(values = rev())
  )
```

I appreciate any pointers or solutions you may have!

Thanks,
Aram

Comment: Could you also show your command for plotting?

Comment: @ChiPak; I've updated my post to include this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the *avg* columns and the *SEM* (standard error) columns need to stay together. This requires to reshape two value columns *simultaneously*. [See section 3.a of *Efficient reshaping using data.tables*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) for more details.

Therefore, we start with the data in wide format (`df_group_sum.wide`). To be in line with the code provided by the OP, only magnitudes are plotted.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

molten <- melt(
  data.table(df_group_sum.wide), id.vars = "strain", 
  measure.vars = patterns("avg_mag$", "magSEM$"),
  value.name = c("avg", "SEM"))[
    , variable := forcats::lvls_revalue(variable, c("test_mag", "train_mag"))][]
molten
```

> ```
>         strain  variable        avg         SEM
>  1:         N2  test_mag 0.11216346 0.003356197
>  2: acy-1(LOF)  test_mag 0.11344703 0.004432513
>  3: acy-1(GOF)  test_mag 0.15930173 0.009190666
>  4:      pde-4  test_mag 0.10539793 0.004321503
>  5:     unc-43  test_mag 0.03700001 0.004008874
>  6:      crh-1  test_mag 0.08236270 0.006648664
>  7:      glr-1  test_mag 0.04416207 0.005758609
>  8:     avr-14  test_mag 0.13578655 0.005244622
>  9:         N2 train_mag 0.19305574          NA
> 10: acy-1(LOF) train_mag 0.19297077          NA
> 11: acy-1(GOF) train_mag 0.21291686          NA
> 12:      pde-4 train_mag 0.12741701          NA
> 13:     unc-43 train_mag 0.08412398          NA
> 14:      crh-1 train_mag 0.11721095          NA
> 15:      glr-1 train_mag 0.11541361          NA
> 16:     avr-14 train_mag 0.17922739          NA
> ```

```
ggplot(molten, 
  aes(strain, avg, ymin = avg - SEM, ymax = avg + SEM, fill = variable)) +
geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
geom_errorbar(width=.1, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightseagreen", "indianred1")) +
theme_bw() +  
labs(fill = "", y = "Magnitude", x = "")
```

[image]

---

The OP also has provided a data.frame in long format `df_group_sum.long` which does contain more data than `df_group_sum.wide`. These should be plotted as well, now.

By looking at the variable names

```
unique(df_group_sum.long$variable)
```

> ```
>  [1] test_avg_dist  test_avg_dura  test_avg_mag   test_avg_prob  test_avg_spd  
>  [6] test_distSEM   test_duraSEM   test_magSEM    test_probSEM   test_spdSEM   
> [11] train_avg_dist train_avg_dura train_avg_mag  train_avg_prob train_avg_spd 
> [16] train_distSEM  train_duraSEM  train_magSEM   train_probSEM  train_spdSEM  
> 20 Levels: test_avg_dist test_avg_dura test_avg_mag test_avg_prob ... train_spdSEM
> ```

the data.frame seems to contain aggregated data (`avg` and `SEM`) of five different variables (`dist`, `dura`, `mag`, `prob`, `spd`) of two data sets (`train` and `test`). Again, `avg` and `SEM` need to stay together on one row for plotting bar charts with error bars.

Unfortunately, the naming scheme is inconsistent. It would have been better if the variables containing standard errors would have been named similar to `train_avg_mag`, e.g., `train_SEM_mag` instead of `train_magSEM`.

So, the first step is to split up the `variable` names to get the different groups separately:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df_group_sum.long)
DT[, c("dataset", "measure", "variable") := 
     DT[, tstrsplit(variable, "_|SEM$")][is.na(V3), `:=`(V3 = V2, V2 = "SEM")]]
DT
```

> ```
>          strain variable       value dataset measure
>   1:         N2     dist 0.231024472    test     avg
>   2: acy-1(LOF)     dist 0.198503788    test     avg
>   3: acy-1(GOF)     dist 0.238929368    test     avg
>   4:      pde-4     dist 0.247270588    test     avg
>   5:     unc-43     dist 0.148316667    test     avg
>  ---                                                
> 156:      pde-4      spd 0.001445281   train     SEM
> 157:     unc-43      spd 0.004410885   train     SEM
> 158:      crh-1      spd 0.002483946   train     SEM
> 159:      glr-1      spd 0.003190276   train     SEM
> 160:     avr-14      spd 0.001746384   train     SEM
> ```

```
unique(DT[, variable])
```

> "dist" "dura" "mag"  "prob" "spd"

```
unique(DT[, dataset])
```

> "test"  "train"

```
unique(DT[, measure])
```

> "avg" "SEM"

Now, the abbreviated variable names are replaced by their full names using an *update on join*:

```
abbr2full <- data.table(
  variable = c("dist", "dura", "mag"), 
  full = c("Distance", "Duration", "Magnitude")
)
DT[abbr2full, on = "variable", variable := full][]
```

Finally, a facetted plot of all five variables is created. `dcast()` is used to reshape the data from long to a wide format where each row has two measures `avg` and `SEM`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dcast(DT, ... ~ measure), 
       aes(strain, avg, ymin = avg - SEM, ymax = avg + SEM, fill = dataset)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  geom_errorbar(width=.1, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightseagreen", "indianred1")) +
  theme_bw() +  
  labs(fill = "", y = "Average", x = "") + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))
```

[image]